# Подскажите, как сделать процедуру ~File.ReadAllByte(string path, IntPtr p)?

Tags: c#

Т.е. у меня уже есть предварительно выделенный буфер в памяти, и я хочу считать в него файл.

Общая задача - у меня есть множество мелких файлов, мне хочется для ускорения последующей их обработки считать их все в память.

Последовательное считывание в массив строк (string[]) замедляется, примерно после считывания 1000-2000 файлов (т.е. постоянно выполняется считывание ~ по 100 файлов, их обработка, обнуление этого массива строк, и опять его  загрузка. и после 10-20 таких циклов считывание замедляется примерно на порядок.).

Comment: [FileStream.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-8.0). Или, если нужно в неуправляемую память, то [UnmanagedMemoryStream.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.read?view=net-8.0).

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Что за буфер, чем представлен, как выделен, зачем выделен? Чем именно обычное чтение в массив байт не подходит?

Comment: Меньше слов, больше кода! Покажите свой код. То у вас буфер с IntPtr, то массив строк string[].

Comment: Перечитал вопрос, но суть проблемы без кода не ясна. Если у вас что-то где-то замедляется, значит что-то делаете не так. И неуправляемый буфер не спасёт. Давайте конкретнее саму исходную проблему решать, а не проблему изобретения костылей.